# From Bitmap to Uri - Android

Tags: java, android, url, bitmap, uri

In my Project I'm saving a given `Bitmap` to my phone's local gallery with the following method:

```
Bitmap bmp = some_fancy_bitmap;
imgeUrl = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bmp, "some Title", "some_Description");
```

[`MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#insertImage%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) gets the source `Bitmap`, saves it, and returns a `String` with the `URL` to the newly created image, or `null` if the image failed to be stored for any reason.

This is an example of imageUrl I am returned in case of successful saving: `content://media/external/images/media/223`.

I'd now like to pass this `Bitmap` to a new `Activity`, in the form of the `Uri` of the resource.

How can I transform the imageUrl I was returned, or directly the `Bitmap` bmp, into the resource's `Uri`?

**Note:** imageUrl is a `String`, and I want to get an `Uri`, not an `URI`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uri.parse(String url ) Creates a Uri which parses the given encoded URI string.
Parameters:
uriString an RFC 2396-compliant, encoded URI
Returns:
Uri for this given uri string
Throws:
NullPointerException - if uriString is null

Comment: Thks...it was simple as that... ;D